# Nginx Stream разрывается простаивающее соединение через 10 минут

Tags: nginx, tcp-ip

на сервере настроен nginx как прозрачное прокси. Соединение и обмен данными между клиентом и сервером происходят успешно при подключении клиентом к порту 9059, однако если сессия простаивает, то она сбрасывается каждые 10 минут и клиент переподключается снова. Такое поведение не воспроизводится если подключиться клиентом напрямую к серверу. Операционки на балансировщике RHEL8, а апстрим сервере RHEL7. Проверил все параметры тайм-футов в sysctl.conf, везде где фигурирует таймаут 600 поменял, но на ситуацию это не повлияло. Настройки nginx тоже менял по разному, ничего не помогает. Подскажите можно ли как-то избежать этих разрывов?

```
stream {

    upstream upstreamserver {
        server 10.200.200.111:9059;
    }

    server {
        listen 9059 reuseport;
        proxy_pass upstreamserver ;
        proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Гуглите строку `zone=client_sessions:1m;`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Судя по всему такой функционал доступен только в Nginx Plus, а данный параметр используется при настройке HTTP балансировщика нагрузки, у меня же TCP балансировщик (директива stream).

Comment: Эм? [proxy_timeout](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_timeout)?

Comment: Да спасибо оно, что-то я сглупил.